# How to use Mock HTTP in a Test Class

Tags: unit-test

I've never written a test class which involves an API callout and I'm just now finding out I will get a "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" error.

I apparently need to use a Mock callout. I don't know how to incorporate that into this test class :

```
@isTest

public class SlinkPDFGenerationTest {
  @isTest
  static void testGetSmartlinkPDF() {
   
 // Create test data
    List<SlinkPDFGeneration.Request> requests = new List<SlinkPDFGeneration.Request>();
    SlinkPDFGeneration.Request request = new SlinkPDFGeneration.Request();
    request.inputJSONString = '{"Records":[{"UniqueId":"123"}]}';  
    request.varfilename = 'test';
    request.linkedEntityID = 'abc123';
    requests.add(request);
   
// Call method being tested
    Test.startTest();
    SlinkPDFGeneration.getSmartlinkPDF(requests);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Add assertions
    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Count() FROM ContentVersion]);

    ContentVersion cv = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion LIMIT 1];
    System.assertNotEquals(null, cv);
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId =:cv.ContentDocumentId];
    System.assertNotEquals(null, cdl);
  }
}
```

Can somebody tell me the way to do that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried looking for documentation and/or modules on trailhead?

Comment: I had. I was confused with it. I thought I would come on here and see if maybe I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts#test-callouts

Comment: @DerekF thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very experienced in mock testing classes, but I recently made one that worked for me. I'll leave the code snippet so you can get an idea.

I hope it helps.

```
public  class TestIntegrationApi {

        @isTest 
        static void insertAccountSucess(){
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new UtilsHttpCalloutMockForTests.InsertAccountSucess());
            Account acc = UtilsTestDataFactory.newAccount();
            Test.startTest();
                AccountService.integrarConta(acc.Id);
            Test.stopTest();
        }
}
    
    
global class UtilsHttpCalloutMockForTests {
       
    global class InsertAccountSucess implements HttpCalloutMock {
            global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request){
                HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
                response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                response.setBody('Insert the API response in JSON format here');
                response.setStatusCode(200); // Here Status Code Response 200 = Sucess, 400 = Bad Request, 404 = Not Found e etc...
                return response; 
            }
        }
}
```